# Run with elevated privileges in context of standard user

Tags: c++, windows, security, privileges, createprocess

Want to run an application in the context of Standard User with elevated privileges. Can be assumed that an administrator user's credentials are available.

I tried createprocesswithlogon and createprocessasuser both are running the process in context of Administrator user instead of the standard user.

I tried [Tokenvator](https://github.com/0xbadjuju/Tokenvator)'s steal token concept but of no use. Still ended up running the process in context of Administrator.

Yet to try lpenvironmentblock input in createprocess method.
Any ideas?

Comment: You can have look at [CreateProcessAsUser()] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-rocessthreadsapi-createprocessasusera

Comment: @Mozfox it either runs as Standard user without elevation or in context of Administrative user. There is no middle ground which I am trying to acheive

Comment: Have you looked into using `ShellExecute` with the `runas` verb? There is an example of doing so [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppUACSelfElevation-5bfc52dd)

Comment: @Nickd'Alterio again this will run the process in context of the administrative user and not the standard user